# Android media player to run in background

Tags: android, media-player

I have an android app which runs mediaplayer.It works fine my problem is that when i come or lock the screen the songs gets stopped is there a way to make the media player run in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it run as a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of an activity.